# I am getting an undefined instead of filename

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have a link to an application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php). Now what I am trying to do is that when the user clicks on the "Upload" button, it will display a loading a bar and below that it will display the name of the file which is uploading and a "Cancel" button next to it so the user can cancel the upload if they wish.

The problem though is that it is not retrieving the file name at all. It is displaying it as undefined. So my question is that how can I get the file name to be displayed andd not undefined next to the cancel button?

Below is the javascript function where it starts uploading and where Cancel button function is stored:

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){
  $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex)
    .html('' + imagefilename + 
          '<button type="button" class="imageCancel" cancel_image_file_name="' + 
          imagefilename + '">Cancel</button>');
  $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".imageCancel").on("click", 
    function(event) {
      var cancel_image_file_name = $(this).attr('cancel_image_file_name');
      console.log(cancel_image_file_name) 
      jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?imagefilename=" + cancel_image_file_name)
        return stopImageUpload(2);
  });     
  return true;
}
```

Below is the `cancelimage.php` script where it is supposed to retrieve the name of the file:

```
<?php

$cancel_image_file_name = $_GET["imagefilename"];

?>
```

Comment: Show us the generated HTML from view/source in the browser, not the PHP template so we can see what the browser actually sees.

Comment: when `$('input[type=file]').val()` is used the name of the to be uploaded file is returned.

Comment: It should work correctly .... could you plz post the result from fireBug to see the request

Comment: @Raminson I cant use the `$('input[type=file]').val()`. The reason for this is that lets say I uploaded a file "Tulips.png", then uploaded the same file again, in the server it would save it as "Tulips_2.png", which would not be correct if I used `$('input[type=file]').val()` to pull out the value as it would still state it as "Tulips.png"

Comment: @TheHulk There are no errors stated in fireBug.

Comment: @jfriend00 From the page source it is stating this from the cancelimage.php page: `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  imagefilename in <b>/web/stud/xxxx/xxxx/cancelimage.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />`

Comment: It's a ajax request could you show us the request with the parameters

Comment: @TheHulk In the ajax request it does state this in FireBug: `xxx/Mobile_app/cancelimage.php?imagefilename=undefined
 
`

Comment: that's mean you didn't get the image name correctly from your JS before you send the request

Comment: @TheHulk I know, that is the problem, How can I retrieve the filename from the JS before sending it to the AJAX request? That is really what I should of asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render your html

**ex.**

```
  // html 
     <img src="bla_bla_bla" name="img_1.jpg" id="x" >

 // in your JS
     $imgName = $("#x").attr('name');
```

Then you can send the image name normally with your Ajax